# What kind of histogram does OpenCV CAMSHIFT use, is it ratio or weighted?

Tags: opencv, histogram

I want to know the kind of histogram is used in OpenCV along with the camshift algorithm.

Is it the ratio histogram or is it the weighted histogram?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [this site](http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_3/sidebar.html) explains it well.

If you want to know more about OpenCV histograms, you [check the documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/histograms.html).